# useEffect() doesn't trigger on property object change (Deep object)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which takes a deep object as argument. I want to be able to dynamically alter my component based on the property that I pass - But for some reason my `useEffect()` loop doesn't run the 2nd time that I pass an object, which naturally is due to the fact that it is a deep object which `useEffect()` doesn't "recognize"

My code is as follows:

```
<MyComponent groups={sourceArray}/>

function MyComponent({ groups }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        //Do something
    }, [groups])
```

For clarification, my data is an array of objects.

I did try several things to get this to work - but for some reason, I just cant get my effect loop to trigger:

**First alternative solution which doesn't work (useRef)**

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (prevGroups && !isEqual(prevGroups, groups)) {
        // do something
    }
}, [groups])

const usePrevious = (value) => {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        ref.current = value;
    });
    return ref.current;
};

const prevGroups = usePrevious(groups);
```

**2nd solution which also fails (External library)**

I tried using the following [library](https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect), - Also without any luck.

Conclusively, I'm unsure what's going on here and how I would get my useEffect loop to run on update.

The easy solution would be to remove the dependency array - But that just makes the useEffect loop run infinitely

**Update**

object has the following structure:

[{"name": "123", "id": "1", "children": [{...}]}]

Also, I'm passing the value as a useState(), i.e.:

```
const funcToChangeObj = () => {
    //logic to change sourceArray
    setSourceArray(changedArray)
}
```

Comment: You don't show how you're passing in `sourceArray`, particularly at the point where it updates - but you strongly imply you're mutating it. So the obvious solution is to not do that in the parent component, but pass in a new object reference instead.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of how the data structure for `groups` look like.

Comment: I will update my question

Comment: Make a copy of the array when updating in state so that the object reference changes. Generally speaking, this is what you do in react. It doesn't matter if its a deep object that you are mutating, the object stored in state needs it's reference to change. Do `changedArray.slice()`.

Comment: Try using spread syntax to strip away the object reference before you modify it and update the state.

Comment: @DanPhilip I am guessing this is what you mean `const aboutToChangeThis = [...changedArray]`. Then modifying, then updating. I agree completely. That is better practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setSourceArray(changedArray)` -> `setSourceArray(changedArray.slice())`